# Python input method label gives error while printing it

Tags: python

I am practicing python on my own and struggling to under input method. My program is as below

```
a = (input('Enter any alphabet: '))
print 'type is: ',a
if a=='a':
    print 'The given character is vowel a '
elif a=='e':
    print 'The given character is vowel e'
elif a=='i':
    print 'The given character is vowel i'
elif a=='o':
    print 'The given character is vowel o'
elif a=='u':
    print 'The given character is vowel u'
else:
   print 'The give character is a consonent'
print "Thats all folks"
```

It is giving error when I am entering single digit alphabet as shown below

```
Enter any alphabet: a
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Demo_if_ladder.py", line 1, in <module>
a = input('Enter any alphabet: ')
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Why it is happening, The program works fine if I input single digit alphabet as in single quote but it not accepting single digit alphabet without single quote

Comment: You should use `raw_input`. Btw, it's high time you change to Python 3.x version.

Comment: No. You should use python 3.

Comment: I was told to start with python 2.x as beginner

Comment: Python 2 is being phased out and there is a strong push towards moving everything into python 3. I recommend starting with (and staying with) python 3.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running python 2 from the print statement syntax.
In python 2, `input(...)` tries to run the contents like it was a command. So when you enter something in, python will try to execute it.

The solution to your problem is to use `raw_input(...)` instead which will return a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 2.

In Python 2 input accepts Python commands. You can use raw_input to get the effect you desire.

The single quotes fix the issue because text in Python commands are written in single quotes.

You'll understand clearly if you run the following:

```
a = (input('please, write: "list(range(10))"\n'))
print a
a = raw_input('please, write: "list(range(10))"\n')
print a
```

In Python 3 input works as you expected, but the print statement was changed into a function. In Python 3 you should change

```
print a
```

to

```
print(a)
```